# ¿ Porque cuando ejecuto ajax, se demora unos cuantos segundos en realizar las animaciones?

Tags: ajax

Tengo una petición ajax, donde simplemente envió unos datos y antes de eso tengo una animación, el problema es que antes de hacer el ajax quiero un efecto de cargando pero parece que como es una peticion asincrona se ejecuta primero y de ultimo deja la animacion por lo cual por un corto perido de tiempo pareciera com si no se estuviera ejecutando nada.

Ya he intentado con el beforeSend y no funciona

Muchas gracias, este es el codigo

function queryEmails(callback) {

```
$("#loading").modal('show');

var formSerialize = $("form").serialize();
var rows = $('#QueryEmailsTable  tr').length;

jQuery.ajax({
    url: '/SupervisorManager/FindEmails',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: formSerialize,
    async: false,
    type: 'POST',
    beforeSend: function ()
    {
        document.getElementById("QueryEmailsTable").innerHTML = "";
    },
    success: function (result)
    {
        callback(result, rows);
    },

    complete: function ()
    {
        setTimeout(function ()
        {
            $('#loading').modal('hide');
            document.getElementById("dataInfo").style.display = "block";
        }, 1000);

        onComplete();
    },
    error: function ()
    {
        addFailureMessage("Error, don't load emails campaign info");
    }
});
```

}

Comment: Muestra la parte relavante del html

Comment: @Einer no hay necesidad, lo que realmente me importa, es que porque primero entra al calback del ajax y después me hace la animación del loading

Comment: Siempre se va a ejecutar primero lo que está en success o error y luego lo que está en complete, para mostrar algún tipo de "animación" mientras se realiza la petición debes usar beforeSend, muestra que código estabas usando con éste último

Comment: realmente eso hacia antes, colocaba dentro del beforeSend esto $("#loading").modal('show');, pero al ver que se demoraba un poco, decidí colocarlo antes para ver si se ejecutaba, pero el mismo problema surge, entonces realmente no se que hacer @CamiloVasquez

Comment: Sebastian, intenta agregar un ejemplo donde se pueda reproducir el error y para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Es en una ventana modal que quieres mostrar la animación?

Comment: Si, exacto es una ventana modal @LuisFernando

Answer (score 0):

Te explico lo que entendí, tratas de mostrar una animación en una ventana modal, entonces antes de que se envie tienes que mostrar la ventana modal, y de la unica forma que se me ocurre es un beforesend

```
function queryEmails(callback) {

var formSerialize = $("form").serialize();
var rows = $('#QueryEmailsTable  tr').length;

jQuery.ajax({
    url: '/SupervisorManager/FindEmails',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: formSerialize,
    async: false,
    type: 'POST',
    beforeSend: function ()
    {
        $("#loading").modal('show');
        document.getElementById("QueryEmailsTable").innerHTML = "";
    },
    success: function (result)
    {
        callback(result, rows);
    },

    complete: function ()
    {
        setTimeout(function ()
        {
            $('#loading').modal('hide');
            document.getElementById("dataInfo").style.display = "block";
        }, 1000);

        onComplete();
    },
    error: function ()
    {
        addFailureMessage("Error, don't load emails campaign info");
    }
});
}
```

Otra forma es mostrar la imagen loading dentro del form por ejemplo, pero eso no se si adapta a tus necesidades. Lo mas optimo seria poner el codigo HTML para hacernos una idea de lo que tienes.

Otra forma es esta(Que es la forma en que lo haria yo.)

**HTML**

```
<div class="loader">
   <center>
       <img class="loading-image" src="loading.jpg" alt="loading..">
   </center>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.loading-image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 10;
}
.loader
{
    display: none;
    width:200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    text-align:center;
    margin-left: -50px;
    margin-top: -100px;
    z-index:2;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

**JS**

Siempre usando el beforesend,

```
$.ajax({
  // your ajax code
  beforeSend: function(){
       $('.loader').show()
   },
  complete: function(){
       $('.loader').hide();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Listo, le di a la solución del problema, como son peticiones asíncronas, entonces al Ajax cuando se entra a la función que esta llamando al Ajax, por decirlo así todo el código se ejecuta después de que eso ya este resuelto, o ya haya un callback de la petición, lo único que hice fue que el atributo "async" que estaba en falso lo cambie true, y listo , dejo el código.

function queryEmails(callback) {
    var formSerialize = $("form").serialize();
    var rows = $('#QueryEmailsTable  tr').length;

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: '/SupervisorManager/FindEmails',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: formSerialize,
    async: true,
    type: 'POST',
    beforeSend: function ()
    {
        setDimentionsModal();
        $("#loading").modal('show');
        document.getElementById("QueryEmailsTable").innerHTML = "";
    },
    success: function (result)
    {
        callback(result, rows);
    },

    complete: function ()
    {
        setTimeout(function ()
        {
            $('#loading').modal('hide');
            document.getElementById("dataInfo").style.display = "block";
        }, 1000);

        onComplete();
    },
    error: function ()
    {
        addFailureMessage("Error, don't load emails campaign info");
    }
});
```

}